# inversion of past participle

Tags: sentence-construction, inversion

I came across a sentence to understanding like the following.

> Enclosed is a brochure explaining our services and investment options, per your request.

This sentence is made to place a past participle(enclosed) in front part of the sentence in inversion.

Is it possible and is the sentence correct and natural?

Is there anyone telling me about it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible and is the sentence correct

Yes :) For example, I searched for "enclosed is a brochure" and one of the results was an example sentence from Cambridge Dictionary itself, on the entry for [brochure](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brochure):

> *Enclosed is a brochure that highlights the benefits that you can receive as a corporate donor.*

You can see that the structure of this sentence is almost the same as the one that you supplied.

> and natural?

I'd say that this is natural *in a business context*. The framing is usual for a reasonably formal business email or letter. I wouldn't use it as a template for more casual or everyday text or in conversation, where inversion is much less common (unless you're deliberately trying to be 'different'!).